# How to extract text from .rtf file using python?

Tags: python, error-handling, artificial-intelligence, analysis

I tried tthis but didn't worked for me

from striprtf.striprtf import rtf_to_text
text = read_rtf('file-sample_300kB.rtf')
print(text)

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? What happend? Exception? Unexpected result?

Comment: I want to extract text from .rtf file using python how can i do that ?